# Passing an image source from one window to another

Tags: c#, wpf, image, winforms

I've got a WPF application which contains 2 windows.

Window 1 contains one button and one image, window 2 just contains one image.

When you press the button you would see the source from the first image, in the image on window 2. While both windows are visible at the same time.

I'm having trouble making this work. 
Currently this is my code:

```
namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private string msMapImages = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Images/";
        public MainWindow()
            {
            InitializeComponent();
            Image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(msMapImages + "image.jpg"));
            Window2 win2 = new Window2();
            win2.Show();
        }
        private void Btnsend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window2 win2 = new Window2();
            win2.Image2.Source = Image1.Source;            
        }
    }
}
```

The image loads perfectly in window 1 but the same image won't appear in window 2 when I press the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to have the event setting the content of the second window, where the other window has an ImageControl bound to the content of the parent Content. 
Your question gives me more of a feeling that you are very new to WPF. in this case you should really invest a small amount of time into MVVM. it will quickly pay off.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string msMapImages = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Images/";
    private Window win2 { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(msMapImages + "image.jpg"));
        win2 = new Window2();
        win2.Show();
    }

    private void Btnsend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        win2.Content = Image1.Source;            
    }
}
```

the other window wold look something like this

```
<Window Name ="Window2">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source={Binding .} />
    </Grid>
</Window2>
```

That should be it. in a more complicated situation you would be using a custom class (ViewModel) and setting it as the content instead of the ImageSource which would be a part of the ViewModel class.